# Delete '\' character from a string

Tags: java, string, character, stringbuffer

I have a string that contains lots of '\'(Backslash) characters. Using a loop I want to delete all these characters from the string. For this I used `StringBuffer` class and `deleteCharAt()` method.

This is my code:

```
public class NewClass33 {
public static void main(String args[]){ 

String s = ""\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\"";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(sb.charAt(i)=='\'){
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    } 
  }
}
```

For sample, here I have taken a small string.

But the problem is that, it shows an error in `if` loop. Error message is: "Unclosed character literal".

Comment: Remove first doublequote of string `s` to get rid of "Unclosed character lieral" error, like this:  `String s = "\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\"";`

Comment: Your string doesn't actually contain any backslashes.

Comment: Then it shows the same error in String s: "Unclosed String literal".

Comment: You must escape the backslash by a backslash `sb.charAt(i)=='\\'`

Comment: So convert `if(sb.charAt(i)=='\')` to `if(sb.charAt(i)=='\\')` . But as @JonSkeet pointed out, your string doesn't contain any backslashes. Those backslashes are just escaping your doublequotes.

Comment: And if it *did*, even after the change, if you had multiple consecutive backslashes you'd only remove half of them. It would be better to just use `String.replace`.

Comment: You have one `"` to much before "MARY"

Comment: By replacing `if(sb.charAt(i)=='\')` by `if(sb.charAt(i)=='\\')`, it is working. thanks!

Comment: okay, I understood, there is no backslashes in the string.